# Come back to previous activity via intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I''ve got the following call flow:

External app -> My activity A -> Open browser -> My activity B

From an external app, via `startActivityForResult` it's possible to start my activity A. Activity A can open the browser to see a web site, from web site, the user can click a link and open the link with activity B. Now I'd like to close B and come back to A. How can I do? If I call `finish()` on B, I see the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start activity A again from activity B with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` intent flag. Before that you also need to change the `launch mode` of activity A in the manifest, make it something other than `standard`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

I noticed that, if you don't change the launch mode of activity A, other activities residing on the top of `activity A` will still be cleared but `onNewIntent` will not be called because activity will be destroyed and recreated again.

Comment: There is only one problem: A is called with startActivityForResult from another app, so if I call it from B, I could change the intent of A received from the external app

Comment: You can save the incoming intent in the activity state, and then on `onNewIntent` you can parse the same saved intent, instead of the intent passed to `onNewIntent`.

Comment: Yep, it seems a good strategy, I was thinking it was even a way to put the browser and B in a new "task" and let B close the "task" including the browser activity, but I don't know if it's possible

Comment: It's also possible. But how B will close browser activity as it is started after browser activity?

Comment: I was thinking something like finishAffinity() but I don't know if it works

Comment: It is supported for API level 16 and above.

Comment: Yes, I know but my min is 16

Comment: I haven't used it. But I think it should work. You can try it out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this wrapper to move an Activity into front:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
protected static int moveToFront(Context ctx) {
    int result = 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { // honeycomb
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
        {
               O.Log.d(TAG, "Application executed : " 
                       +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()
                       + "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");  
               // bring to front                
               if (recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf(PACKAGE_NAME) > -1) {                     
                  activityManager.moveTaskToFront(recentTasks.get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
                  result = 1;
                  break;
               }else{
                   result = 2;
               }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

resultant values:

0 - old Android version
1 - ok
2 - fault